# Blue iMac running Debian will not boot Ubuntu from cd drive

Tags: mac, home-server, powerpc

I have a older blue iMac that is running Debian linux.(An old version of about 3 years ago without update.  Doesn't run well after loading)  At the choice of loading linux from  from hd or cd, I choose CD, then the program drops down to CD..., and then nothing.  The Ubuntu cd is from this site.  I tried desktop and also server.  Nothing. How do you mend a broken prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Does your iMac look like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_G3 ?

[image]

Those were using PowerPC processors, you'll need PowerPC version of Ubuntu. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads